# Mondrian/Pivot4j error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException with closure table

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, pivot4j

This is the scenario:

- Pentaho 5.4.0 CE
- Pivot4j Plugin

If in Mondrian XML Schema I insert a dimension with a hierarchy type parent-child  - defined using a closure table - with the following options, **it works well** (that is, I can see the result table and drill down to the parent-child hierarchy elements):

- attribute "nameColumn" **defined** (reference a fact table field)
- attribute "captionColumn" **empty** (no field assigned)

If I try to change the two attributes definition as

- attribute "nameColumn" **defined** (reference a fact table field)
- attribute "captionColumn" **defined** (reference another fact table field)

I get the error from Pivot4J **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2**. It happen only with dimension defined using closure table, in standard dimension I can set the attributes at the same time with no error.

Any idea about it, how I can solve this? It's a problem because I need to use the **captionColumn** attribute that contains label value for the end-user, **nameColumn** instead contains a nickname. I've the same problem in Pentaho 6.0.

This is what I have in the pentaho log:

```
... Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.makeMember(SqlMemberSource.java:1072)
at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren2(SqlMemberSource.java:1004)
at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren(SqlMemberSource.java:881)
at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren(SqlMemberSource.java:854)
at mondrian.rolap.SmartMemberReader.readMemberChildren(SmartMemberReader.java:249)
at mondrian.rolap.SmartMemberReader.getMemberChildren(SmartMemberReader.java:211)
at mondrian.rolap.RolapCubeHierarchy$CacheRolapCubeHierarchyMemberReader.readMemberChildren(RolapCubeHierarchy.java:600)
at mondrian.rolap.RolapCubeHierarchy$CacheRolapCubeHierarchyMemberReader.getMemberChildren(RolapCubeHierarchy.java:696)
at mondrian.rolap.SmartMemberReader.getMemberChildren(SmartMemberReader.java:177)
at mondrian.rolap.RestrictedMemberReader.getMemberChildren(RestrictedMemberReader.java:101)
at mondrian.rolap.SmartRestrictedMemberReader.getMemberChildren(SmartRestrictedMemberReader.java:85)
at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.internalGetMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:186)
at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.getMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:168)
at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.getMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:162)
at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jMember$3.execute(MondrianOlap4jMember.java:111)
at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jMember$3.execute(MondrianOlap4jMember.java:110)
at mondrian.server.Locus.execute(Locus.java:86)
at mondrian.server.Locus.execute(Locus.java:71)
at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jMember.getChildMemberCount(MondrianOlap4jMember.java:105)
at org.pivot4j.impl.QueryAdapter.canExpand(QueryAdapter.java:838)
at org.pivot4j.transform.impl.DrillExpandPositionImpl.canExpand(DrillExpandPositionImpl.java:44)
at org.pivot4j.ui.command.DrillExpandPositionCommand.canExecute(DrillExpandPositionCommand.java:69)
at org.pivot4j.ui.AbstractPivotRenderer.getCommands(AbstractPivotRenderer.java:146)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer.access$100(TableRenderer.java:60)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer$3.handleTreeNode(TableRenderer.java:649)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableHeaderNode.walkChildrenAtColIndex(TableHeaderNode.java:915)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableHeaderNode.walkChildrenAtColIndex(TableHeaderNode.java:931)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer.renderBody(TableRenderer.java:611)
at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer.render(TableRenderer.java:483)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.ViewHandler.render(ViewHandler.java:597)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.ViewHandler.structureChanged(ViewHandler.java:963)
at org.pivot4j.impl.PivotModelImpl.fireStructureChanged(PivotModelImpl.java:833)
at org.pivot4j.impl.PivotModelImpl$1.queryChanged(PivotModelImpl.java:111)
at org.pivot4j.impl.QueryAdapter.fireQueryChanged(QueryAdapter.java:197)
at org.pivot4j.impl.QueryAdapter.fireQueryChanged(QueryAdapter.java:182)
at org.pivot4j.impl.QueryAdapter.onQuaxChanged(QueryAdapter.java:1109)
at org.pivot4j.impl.QueryAdapter$1.quaxChanged(QueryAdapter.java:79)
at org.pivot4j.impl.Quax.fireQuaxChanged(Quax.java:163)
at org.pivot4j.impl.Quax.regeneratePosTree(Quax.java:648)
at org.pivot4j.transform.impl.PlaceHierarchiesOnAxesImpl.placeHierarchies(PlaceHierarchiesOnAxesImpl.java:88)
at org.pivot4j.transform.impl.PlaceHierarchiesOnAxesImpl.addHierarchy(PlaceHierarchiesOnAxesImpl.java:119)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.NavigatorHandler.addHierarhy(NavigatorHandler.java:548)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.NavigatorHandler.addHierarhy(NavigatorHandler.java:516)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.NavigatorHandler.onDropOnAxis(NavigatorHandler.java:392)
at org.pivot4j.analytics.ui.NavigatorHandler.onDropOnAxis(NavigatorHandler.java:365)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
... 77 more
```

Comment: I also have same problem. Posted a bug - https://github.com/mysticfall/pivot4j/issues/194

Comment: I think it's a mondrian bug, not pivot4j.